# Where include data.toString()

Tags: node.js

I would like to read a file in format `html`

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');

// createServer = créer le serveur
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('index.html', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("Ce fichier n'existe pas");
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.end('Hello World ');
            //console.log(data.toString());
        }  
    })
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at   http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I would like to know where I have to include `data.toString` into my code please?

```
 console.log(data.toString());
```

I can put it into my `else` ?

```
else {
       res.statusCode = 200;
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
       res.end('Hello World ');
        //console.log(data.toString());
 }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: res.end(data.toString ())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply checking if the `index.html` file exists or not,
if it does you send `Hello World`  as the response and if it does not you end up with a 404.
On this basis this code would be fine:

```js
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// createServer = créer le serveur
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.exists(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"), (exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            //res.end('Hello World ');
            res.end(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "index.html")).toString())
        } else {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("Ce fichier n'existe pas");
        }
    });

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at   http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the file and send it to the client you can do something like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');

// createServer = créer le serveur
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('index.html', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("Ce fichier n'existe pas");
        } else {
            const htmlText = data.toString(); // just create a variable and send it to the client or do whatever you want
            console.log(htmlText)
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(htmlText);
            //console.log(data.toString());
        }  
    })
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at   http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```